# Excel: TEXTJOIN from a range if conditions are met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've encountered a problem in Excel that I don't know how to approach solving.

[image]

There are two tables in the image above.

Table 1 is a list of gifts exchanged between individuals, with the giver and the receiver identified. (I'm using "gifts" and "people" to make it easier to discuss here. In reality these are pieces of equipment exchanging control signals. This table can be hundreds of rows long.)

Table 2, columns E and F, is a list of unique person-pairs (irrespective of giver and receiver). I have already written formulas to search columns A and B and return only unique pairs in E and F. Now, for each unique pair, I need to return all of the gifts exchanged between the two individuals in column G (I have manually entered what column G *should* contain with a working formula.

I'm not even sure where to begin with this problem. Column G3's formula should have something like the following in it:

```
=and(or(B3=$E$3,C3=$E$3),or(B3=$F$3,C3=$F$3)),A3,"")
```

But then, the cell needs to search the entire range B:B and C:C and TEXTJOIN every A:A in which the conditions are met.

I am fine using VBA for a solution (even then, I'm not sure where to begin), but would prefer not; the data will be imported into another piece of software and that software can't execute VBA code.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FILTER

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(A:A,((B:B=$E$3)+(C:C=$E$3))*((B:B=$F$3)+(C:C=$F$3)),""))
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe how easy that was. Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: Let me rephrase this; [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihf7n.png) is an over-the-top option to do all at once: `=UNIQUE(REDUCE({"Person 1","Person 2","Items Exchanged"},BYROW(B2:C9,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN("|",,SORT(a,,,1),TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(A2:A9,MMULT(--(B2:B9=a),{1,1})*MMULT(--(C2:C9=a),{1,1})))))),LAMBDA(b,c,VSTACK(b,TEXTSPLIT(c,"|")))))`..... right, I need weekend =)

Comment: @JvdV, I want to understand your array formula. But I can't get it to work in my workbook for me to poke around in it. Can you see what's going on with it here: https://axiagrp-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/p/steven/EW4occxlXVdJgpQM-lQjymUBuUZFambDuYsxwIlJ4HXYAw?e=hQuXeU

Comment: @StevenBunker, have a look [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmlmnAMqhNdLgYZK9e6i92Tw_WMHIQ?e=1nuFCJ)

Answer (score 0):

This is just an extension of @ScottCraner's answer, to generate the array version, that doesn't require to have as input **Person 1** and **Person 2** columns.

In cell `E1` you can put the following formula:

```
= LET(ux, UNIQUE(TOCOL(B2:C9,,TRUE)), r, B2:B9, g, C2:C9, items, A2:A9,
  rMatch, XMATCH(r, ux), gMatch, XMATCH(g, ux),
  sorted, BYROW(HSTACK(gMatch, rMatch), LAMBDA(r, CONCAT(SORT(r,,,TRUE)))),
  idx, XMATCH(UNIQUE(sorted), sorted), pa, INDEX(g, idx), pb, INDEX(r, idx),
  gifts, MAP(pa, pb, LAMBDA(a,b, TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,
    FILTER(items, ((g=a) + (r=a)) * ((g=b) + (r=b)))))),
  VSTACK({"Person 1","Person 2","Items Exchanged"}, HSTACK(pb, pa, gifts))
)
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

Notice this solution preserves the order of the expected output of the question.

### Explanation

`LET` function is used for easy reading and composition. The first step is to identify unique pairs of `[Giver, Receivers]` regardless of the order. Each column is identified as `g` and `r` respectively.

The name `ux`, is used to identify unique values from both columns `g`, `r` as follows:

```
UNIQUE(TOCOL(B2:C9,,TRUE))
```

it returns:

```
Sam
Sally
Henry
Mike
```

We use the third input argument of `TOCOL` to append by columns instead of by rows.

The names `rMatch` and `gMatch` identify index positions that match unique names (`ux`). Here the intermediate result for both columns:

```
gMatch rMatch
2      1
1      2
3      2
4      3
3      1
2      1
2      3
1      3
```

We need to eliminate duplicated pairs. If we sort each row in ascending order by column:

```
gMatch rMatch
1      2
1      2
2      3
3      4
1      3
1      2
2      3
1      3
```

then if we concatenate both numbers on each row, we are able to identify duplicated pairs. The above steps are accomplished via `sorted` name:

```
BYROW(HSTACK(rMatch, gMatch), LAMBDA(r, CONCAT(SORT(r,,,TRUE))))
```

It is important to set the optional input argument `[by_col]` to `TRUE` in `SORT` function to ensure we want to sort by column each row. The result is an array that on each row has concatenated columns of the above-sorted values.

The name `idx`, has only the index positions of unique pairs:

```
XMATCH(UNIQUE(sorted), sorted)
```

**Note**: If the `ux` values don't appear in both columns then `gMatch` or `rMatch` will have some `#N/A` values. This would mean in the input data not all pair combination are present, maybe it is an indication some data clean-up is required first in your real problem. If not, then we can exclude such cases as follow: `FILTER(idx, ISNUMBER(idx))` and name it `idExcl` for example and use `idExcl` in `pa`, `pb` definitions.

Now `pa`, `pb` have the unique pairs values from `g` and `r`. The name `gifts` uses the logic from @ScottCraner's answer but uses `MAP` to have an array result, so there is no need to drag down the formula.

Finally, we put them all together to generate the expected result via `VSTACK` and `HSTACK` functions.

Comment: Thank you. I will study this.