# Format range of cells (code format, not colour) conditionally on range of cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a range of cells that are being displayed as either text string or percentages.

[image]

I'm currently using the `TEXT(XX,"0.00")` individually on each cell, then concatenating the range using `TEXTJOIN` on the range.

Eg the formula in `N2` is `=IF(ISNA(C2),TEXT(C2,"0.0"),C2)` and the formula in `W2` is `=CHAR(34)&TEXTJOIN(CHAR(34)&", "&CHAR(34),TRUE,L2:T2)&CHAR(34)`.

Is there a way that I can output this without having to do thge two setps?

I thought it might be something like this: `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(34)&", "&CHAR(34), TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(C2:R2),TEXT(C2:R2,"0.00"),C2:R2))`, but obviously this won't apply to a range of cells.

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74658982/excel-textjoin-from-a-range-if-conditions-are-met), but it not quite what I'm after.

Comment: *Is there a way that I can output this without having to do thge two setps?* If you want 2 different outputs you need 2 different formulas. What do you mean with two steps?

Comment: Is `=BYROW(A2:J11,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(",",,""""&TEXT(r,"0,00")&"""")))` what you are after? Note that string values default to their original string if the `TEXT()` format does not apply. No need for the `IF()`.

Comment: Do you need to ignore empty cells i.e. the second argument to TEXTJOIN? If so, you will need the 'helper' cells you currently have to explicitly return "" before passing to TEXTJOIN, otherwise the TEXT function will resolve to a "0.0" string that TEXTJOIN will include.

Comment: P.S. it looks like the TEXT function cannot be called as an array i.e. if you need to use different formats in each column, you MUST use helper cells to apply those formats i.e. TEXT(C2:R2, C1:R1) will not work, where C1:R1 contains the format strings e.g. "0.00"

Comment: Turns out you **can** pass an array of format_text in by hard-coding a list like `{"0.00";"0.0";...}` or defining a Named Range that RefersTo such a list, BUT I discovered that results in weird behaviour -> the entire list gets generated multiple times (when nested in TEXTJOIN), once for each format_text value - which is **not** what you are after!

Comment: @RobBaker, it's actually perfectly possible. In your testing, maybe swap the semi-colon to a comma (or backslash depending on locale) for a vertical array. Ranges will also work fine, named or not (at least for me).

Comment: I meant *horizontal* array =)

Comment: @JvdV Your `BYROW` appears to do what I need. I had to change the comma to a full stop in `0,00` but other than that, it seems perfect! Are you able to elaborate as to what the `r` is doing in the `TEXT` formula in the answer below and I'll mark as correct?

Comment: @JvdV - turns out I needed to add the " marks explicitly, rather than pass them into TEXT as part of the argument i.e. `TEXT(value, """" & cell_with_format_string & """")` worked as you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
=BYROW(A2:J11,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(",",,""""&TEXT(r,"0.00")&"""")))
```

Where 'r' is simply a named variable/parameter that holds the values of the current row in the iteration (`BYROW()` does iterate the given range row-by-row).

Also note that string values default to their original string if the `TEXT()` format does not apply. No need for `IF()` here.